# Can block chain store tabular data other than account balance？

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ethereum

In normal cases, block chain can store tractions. If I want to store complex data structure like tabular data in a data base, can any open source project do it without modifying too many codes?

Answer (score 2):

I will let someone answer for other platforms, but for [Hyperledger Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fabric_model.html#ledger-features), you can maintain application state in an arbitrary data model in a database such as CouchDB (plans for supporting additional databases are being developed).

The [Marbles sample application](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/chaincode/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go) is a decent example of managing more complex data model than a single account value.